# How do I get and validate JSON data from a web site with Python?

Tags: python, json

I Need to create cronjob to test the website whether the data is retrieved for every one hour.

Initially have tried by pasted the json data into text file and validated the data by encoding and decoding it. Now i need the real time data(json data) to get loaded on every time running the cron job. used urllib2 but it is not getting the request response from the url.

Url -> on loading -> through firebug gives url to execute and to json data from that. how can i import or parse such url into python. Please get me with an example.

my steps:
create shedule

```
     1.45 08 * * 1-5 /home/user/myfile/daily_verifydata.sh >> /home/user/cronlog.log
```

daily_verifydata.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh
    python /home/user/path/Dashboard_test.py
```

Dashboard_test.py

```
    import json
    import urllib2

    f = open('test.txt','r') # open in read mode
    data = f.read()
    print data

    # How to Parse the json from the URL to python

    data_string = json.dumps(data)
    print '\n''ENCODED:', data_string

    decoded = json.loads(data_string)
    print '\n''DECODED:', decoded

    # Validating data through decoded output.
```

If possible parsing through curl, need to know the syntax

Thanks, vijay

Comment: I don't see how `cron` is relevant there. Please try to put only relevant information into your questions in the future.

Comment: what url are you trying to make a request to? please post your urllib2 attempt

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using requests

```
import requests
import simplejson

session = requests.session()
# I presume your site has authentication
response = session.post(URL_TO_LOGIN, {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        })
response = session.get(URL_TO_JSON)
if response.ok:
    simplejson.loads(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

For retrieveing your JSON in bash script — you can use nice tool [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#json)

If you'd like to pull JSON from python script — best option is [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) lib

And for validation, it it's complex — [JSONSchema](http://json-schema.org/)